# nginx Access to Subfolder Download the File instead of Return Forbidden

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

This is my main `.conf`:

```
  server {
    # Default configuration
    server_name dev.mysite.com;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    index index.php index.html;
    charset utf-8;
    root /opt/www;

    # Logging
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    location /manager {
        error_log /var/log/nginx/manager_error.log ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/manager_access.log ; 
        alias /opt/www/manager;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @laravel ;
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;

        }
     }

    location ~/site/ {
       deny all;
       return 404;
    }

}

server {
    server_name stage.mysite.com
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    index index.php index.html;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.site.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.site.log;

    root /opt/www/site;
     location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }
    location ~*\.php {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;

            }
}
```

Basically, I have two sites, one under `/opt/www/manager` and one under `/opt/www/site`. When I access `dev.mysite.com/manager` I can see the application working. But when I access `dev.mysite.com/site` I get the download of `/opt/www/site/index.php`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put a default try file directive before any location:

```
 try_files $uri =404;
```